# Antonymie d' «engrener » : ce que font les/ce qu'on fait aux dents de la fermeture à glissière ?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, terminologie, antonyme

On connaît la *fermeture à glissière/Éclair/à crémaillère*, aussi appelée par certains le « zipper » ou la « tirette » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermeture_%C3%89clair)) un système de fermeture où des « dents de métal ou de matière plastique s'engrènent au moyen d'un curseur » ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2099503)), plus précisément « le passage d'une navette, appelée curseur, comportant deux gorges qui se rejoignent, permet d'engrener les dents ou de les séparer » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermeture_%C3%89clair#Principe)). De la « perspective » du *curseur* pour ainsi dire on dit entre autres qu' « [...] il assemble leurs maillons lorsqu'il est déplacé dans un sens; déplacé dans l'autre sens, il les désunit » ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8888650)). On utilise généralement une tirette (articulée) pour faire glisser le curseur.

- Quel verbe est employé le plus fréquemment pour exprimer techniquement l'action contraire ou antonyme d'[*engrener*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/engr%C3%A9ner/1) (« Engager deux choses l'une dans l’autre par des dents, des crans. », [Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E1643)) dans ce contexte ; pourquoi ?
- Quels verbes viennent familièrement à l'esprit pour décrire ce que font les/qu'on fait aux *dents* d'une fermeture à glissière quand on la
  ferme/l'ouvre ; ces verbes permettent-ils l'emploi de *dents* autant comme sujet (la relation entre les dents qui s'engrènent) que comme objet (le curseur permet d'engrener les dents) de l'action ?

Comment: Moi je l'engage. Engager un engrenage est me semble correct du point de vue de la mécanique, ça s'emploie aussi pour un moteur il me semble.

Comment: @Laure La fermeture, en fait quoi au juste est engagé ; mais les dents de la fermeture s'engagent-elles, les unes dans les autres ? N'hésite pas à répondre !

Comment: Je ne refuse pas de répondre mais je n'ai pas encore assez d'éléments scientifiques pour répondre, ce n'est ni de la grammaire, ni de l'étymologie.  Un physicien, et il y en a ici, aura certainement des mots plus appropriés que les miens.  Moi je dis quelque chose mais quelqu'un d'autre peut dire autre chose d'aussi valable. Oui pour moi les dents s'engagent les unes dans les autres comme un mécanisme à roue dans un moteur ou une montre (enfin les montres à mécanisme). Ce n'est pas la fermeture qui s'engage en fait ce sont les dents de la fermeture.

Answer (score 2):

> *Désengagez* les dents de la fermeture à glissière pour *ouvrir* cette dernière.

pour signifier qu’elles ont été sciemment (ou techniquement) maintenues les unes contre les autres.

> Toto, *dè-coince* ta fermeture Éclair !

… même demande exprimée beaucoup plus familièrement.

Answer (score 1):

Voici quelques autres propositions :

> Désolidariser les dents...
>
> Dégager...
>
> Désunir...
>
> Détacher...
>
> Désemboîter...
>
> Désimbriquer...

et bien sûr:

> [Désengrener](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9sengrener/24352)...